# Correct way to check if DocumentDB object exists

Tags: c, azure-cosmosdb

In Microsoft examples I saw two ways to check if DocumentDb object like Database, DocumentCollection, Document etc. exists :

First is by creating a query:

```
Database db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(x => x.Id == DatabaseId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
if (db == null)
    {
        await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = DatabaseId });
    }
```

The second one is by using "try catch" block:

```
    try
    {
       await this.client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseName));
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException de)
    {
        if (de.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
           await this.client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = databaseName });
         }
         else
         {
             throw;
          }
    }
```

What is the correct way to do this procedure in terms of performance?

Comment: I use this technique when I just want to check it exists, but not create it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the new `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` in the DocumentDB SDK instead of both these approaches, if that's what you're trying to do.

In terms of server resources (request units), a `ReadDocumentAsync` is slightly more lightweight than `CreateDatabaseQuery`, so you should use that when possible.

Comment: Thanks. I was using an old version of DocumentDB SDK and the function wasn't present.

Answer (score 9):

I've just seen the try/catch example in one of the Microsoft provided sample project and it got me baffled, as it is plain wrong: you don't use try/catch for control flow.

Never.

This is just bad code. The new SDK provides  CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync  which I can only hope doesn't just hide this shit. In older lib just use the query approach, unless you want to get shouted at by whoever is going to review the code.