# Alternative to / how to CreateStoredProcedureIfNotExists in CosmosDb?

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client` 2.x, but there appears not to be an API code to do a `CreateStoredProcedureIfNotExists`, [like there is generally is for other operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674478/correct-way-to-check-if-documentdb-object-exists).

Is there an option better than ignoring the `Exception` I'll get if it already exists ? (if it doesn't exist, I want to create it - there's no value I can see in doing a query to validate the need before I start given that my very next action will be do do a Create [with a race condition in the case of competing writers])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK internally, when you use the `IfNotExists` methods, will do the exact same thing for you (handle the exception and create the item for you that is), that's why they return the `Resource` object in the response. Because they read it.

You can simply create an extension method for `IDocumentClient` that does just that, and use this method instead in order to keep your code clean.

It is a direct read anyway on a document that's less than 1kb so you will be paying just a single RU for this operation.

Comment: Good points; that's pretty much [what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742523/11635)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
let private createStoredProcedureOrIgnore (client: IDocumentClient) (collectionUri: Uri) (name, body): Async<float> = async {
    try let! r = client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(collectionUri, StoredProcedure(Id = name, Body = body)) |> Async.AwaitTaskCorrect
        return r.RequestCharge
    with DocDbException ((DocDbStatusCode sc) as e) when sc = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict -> return e.RequestCharge }
let createStoredProcIfNotExists (log: ILogger) client collUri (sprocName,sprocBody) = async {
    let! t, ru = createStoredProcedureOrIgnore client collUri (sprocName,sprocBody) |> Stopwatch.Time
    log.Information("Created stored procedure {sprocId} rc={ru} t={ms}", sprocName, ru, (let e = t.Elapsed in e.TotalMilliseconds)) }
```

The RC is `1.67` for the `Conflict` and `6.67` for the does not exist case [for my case](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/c9590a646b57e9ba97808f9f50ac5115f5966fe5/src/Equinox.Cosmos/Cosmos.fs#L299)